# How to open .bashrc in Cygwin

Tags: android, bash, path, android-ndk, cygwin

When I try to compile my Android NDK program, it shows the following error:

```
Program "${SA}\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd" not found in PATH
```

(the value of the environment variable "SA" is C:)

I am using Cygwin on Windows 7. How do I open my `.bashrc` file? I read that I need to add the following lines to my `.bashrc` to fix the problem:

```
NDK_HOME=/opt/android-ndk-r8


export NDK_HOME
```

But I am not sure how to open `.bashrc` and edit the file as I have never done this before.

Comment: The .bashrc file is a plain-text file located in the home-directory of a Linux user (that uses bash).

Comment: By the way, you must add this line at the end of the file **export NDK_HOME="/opt/android-ndk-r8"** That should do the trick

Comment: It's not what you ask android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd does not need or make use of cygwin. The error message comes from a program that also does not use cygwin and does not recognize ${SA} variable. It probably does not even recognise that ${SA} is a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
echo "NDK_HOME=/opt/android-ndk-r8 export NDK_HOME" >> ~/.bashrc
```

be sure to restart your cygwin window afterwards

Comment: You don't need to restart the window, or even your shell; just copy-and-paste the command to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of text editors available under Cygwin, either installed by default or installable by using `setup.exe`.

vi/vim is probably the most common. It has a bit of a learning curve. Run `vimtutor` from your command line for a tutorial.

If you're very ambitious, you can try emacs. Run `emacs` from the command prompt, then <kbd>Control-H</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to run the built-in tutorial.

nano is a simpler and more user-friendly editor. It shows the most common commands at the bottom of the screen, including a help command. It may be the best one to start with.

You can use Windows editors like Notepad or Wordpad, but they're likely to add Windows-style end-of-line markers to any files you edit. You can use the `dos2unix` command (`man dos2unix` for more information) to fix that up, but IMHO that's more trouble than it's worth unless you *really* like Windows editors more than Unix-style editors.

The `echo` command in Henry's answer is a quick-and-dirty way to add a single line to a file. If you want to do anything more complex (say, deleting or changing lines, or adding lines other than at the very end), you'll need a real editor. To edit your `.bashrc`:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

(or use another editor of your choice).